# All files in SMB share have executable bit when they shouldn't have

Tags: permission, smb

I have a samba share on a Linux machine `SHARE`. I then mounted `SHARE` on my MacOS computer on dir `dir`. However, when I list the files in `dir`, all files had the executable bit. If I mount `SHARE` on my Linux computer, none of them have the executable bit. Why does this happen?

This problem seems to have [existed for some time](https://serverfault.com/questions/728667/file-permissions-issue-on-os-x-el-capitan-and-smb-share).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What exactly should I clarify?